# Trying to filter non-hovered elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image gallery. Basically I am trying to go for something that lets the hovered image maintain its styling properties but the background (non-hovered images, I should say) filter to grayscale.

This is my first project and I am trying to push myself. I am making some mistakes but learning from each one. Your help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<section id="image-gallery">
            <div class="container">
            <div id="imageboxing" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/boxing.png">
            <div class="imagetext">
            <h3>BOXING</h3>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="imagekb" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/kickboxing.png">
            <div class="imagetext">
            <h3>KICKBOXING</h3>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="muaythai" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/muaythai.png">
            <div class="imagetext">
            <h3>MUAYTHAI</h3>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="wrestling" class="disciplines">
            <img src="images/martial-arts-banner/wrestling.png">
            <div class="imagetext">
            <h3>WRESTLING</h3>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".disciplines img").hover(function(){
        var images = $(".disciplines img");
        $(this).toggleClass("active-image");
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).next().find('h3').slideToggle();
        if (images.not(".active-image") {
            $(images).css("filter", blur("20px"));

        }




    });
```

Comment: Create jsfiddle so we can understand your code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#image-gallery img").hover(function(){ // on hover of image
      $(this).toggleClass("active-image");
      $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
      $(this).parent().css({"filter": ""}); //remove it's parent  filter css
      $('img').not($(this)).parent().css({"filter":'blur(5px)'}); //add filter css to all othe images parent-div apart from thr current clicked-one
  }, function () { //when hover-out
      $('.disciplines').css({"filter": ""}); //remove filter css from all div
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="image-gallery">
    <div class="container">
    <div id="imageboxing" class="disciplines">
    <img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1dizJKFXXXXa_XFXXq6xXFXXXs/Closed-Type-Boxing-Helmet-Head-Protector-For-Taekwondo-Karate-Tai-MMA-Muay-Thai-Kickboxing-Competition-Training.jpg_50x50.jpg">
    <div class="imagetext">
    <h3>BOXING</h3>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="imagekb" class="disciplines">
    <img src="http://www.days-gym.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/days-gym-website-logo.png">
    <div class="imagetext">
    <h3>KICKBOXING</h3>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="muaythai" class="disciplines">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/favicons/50x/ded1fa7e09a93f576a8dc1060fbf82f7e63076e47a08abd0cf27887f.png?ca1416448b5d5bfb6c7465ba2cb5e0d4">
    <div class="imagetext">
    <h3>MUAYTHAI</h3>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrestling" class="disciplines">
    <img src="https://iawrestle.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/screen-shot-2017-06-14-at-10-35-09-am.png?w=50&h=50&crop=1">
    <div class="imagetext">
    <h3>WRESTLING</h3>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Alive to Die. Unfortunately this adds the filter effect to all images on the page, but I only want it to be within this section of id image-gallery

Comment: @CoderAz  do this:- `$("#image-gallery img").hover(function(){` I ave changed it in my code too